# IntelliJ IDEA cannot locate my txt file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory

Before anyone asks, yes, I did search through Stack Overflow to try to find the answer to this issue. Others have had it before, and I have tried all the solutions presented to them, but none of them have seemed to work. Maybe some of you can identify the problem where I can't see anything wrong.

Simply, IntelliJ is not able to find the location of my file, `test.txt`. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Main {
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
}
```

Here is where `test.txt` is located in my directory:

[image]

It's located in the main project directory of my working directory. I've tried everything, from taking ".txt" off the file when I try call it, to going to the `Run > Edit Configurations` menu to make sure my working directory is correct. I also tried putting `test.txt` inside the `src/` folder, but that did not work either.

Can anyone make a theory as to why the file can't be located?

Comment: Have you tried giving full path for your file?

Comment: Yes, tried that already.

Comment: Where is the file located in the output folder? This is the relevant position for running your program. When it is in the classes folder just put a leading slash "/" in front of the path like "test.txt" and load it with Main.class.getRessourceAsStream("/test.txt");

Comment: Also try creating another file with relative path and check where it is created. Obvious expectation is the same path for your test.txt

Comment: Good practice is also to put your Java source files to src/main/java and your resources to src/main/resources as is the default maven convention.

Comment: @Jürgen Now I assume by output folder, you mean out/ ? It was actually not in there at all, so I added a test.txt file to test. It is still not picking it up. I also tried your suggestion of including the .txt file in my classes folder, but Main.class.getRessourceAsStream("/test.txt") gives me the error "Invalid method declaration; return type required". I'm currently searching how to solve that error.

Comment: @hchaznedaroglu If I create a new file it just gets created in the src folder, with the other classes. But I'm still unable to locate it.

Comment: @Jurgen I was able to partially solve the issue by using InputStream as opposed to FileInputStream, thanks for the suggestion to use getResourceAsStream!

Comment: putting just `test.txt` means it's in `src` folder, which is not true, you should put `../test.txt`

Comment: By the way, which error do you get? And your code example is not compilable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the working directory is set right, by doing `new File("").getAbsolutePath()`.

Then, it is just a matter of having the right relative path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Meo. getAbsolutePath worked pretty well and I was able to locate where my files were getting generated from.
As for how I ended up solving this problem, I switched from a Windows platform to a Mac platform and suddenly my files were able to be read. I'm not exactly if that's relevant or if I did something differently, but it did end up working.